# In Java, ArrayList always reading as .size() 0 to while loop, even though it is implemented when it is created

Tags: java, arraylist, size

So, I have a method that's meant to be a basic combat engine. Creates two ArrayLists, one for the good guys, and another from another method that gives a random number of monster objects for them to fight.
The monster ArrayList is implemented with the returned ArrayList from another method, getRandomMonster(). I've checked, then double checked, and that interaction is working as intended.  There is always at least one monster object in the List.
And this is verified by printing list.size(). But, all of the if and while checks in the method are acting like list.size() returns 0.
No hyperbole- in the same run where list.size() was returning 2, the while loop was acting as if it was 0. I'm stumped.

```
public void runCombat() {
        ArrayList<Knight> goodies = data.activeKnights;
        ArrayList<MOB> baddies = data.getRandomMonsters();
        System.out.println(baddies);
        view.printBattleText(baddies, data.activeKnights);
        while ((baddies.size() > 0) || (goodies.size() > 0)) {
            goodTurn(baddies,goodies);
            badTurn(baddies,goodies);
            }
        if (baddies.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Huzzah, victory!");
        } else if (data.activeKnights.size() <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Thou hath been defeated. Scrub.");
        }
    }
```

Run showing baddies.size() !=0
[image]

warning showing that baddies.size() is *always* 0
[image]

Comment: Hmm? You loop "while baddies OR goodies > 0". (Also, "Thou hast".)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your `while` loop, try using  `while ((baddies.size() > 0) && (goodies.size() > 0))`. Now your `while` loop is running as long as your first condition `baddies.size() > 0` is true and if it's true, then it will not check if `goodies.size() > 0` or not. If you use `&&`, as soon as one of the list is empty, condition in `while` will be false and your loop will stop.

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue. Of course, as soon as I fixed this one, 3 others raised their ugly heads, but i think i've got it all ironed out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As your compiler warning says, your if statement can only ever be true. This is because the while loop will only ever exit once `baddies.size()` becomes zero, and therefore by the time it gets to your if statement `baddies.size() == 0` will always be true.

I suspect this is a logic problem and that you actually want the while loop to end once either of `baddies.size()` or `goodies.size()` becomes zero (whereas the way you have it now waits until they are both zero). Having `while (baddies.size() != 0 && goodies.size() != 0)` will solve this.

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue. Of course, as soon as I fixed this one, 3 others raised their ugly heads, but i think i've got it all ironed out. Thanks a lot!